# Why is this decorator returning 'result' first, then print statement?

Tags: python

```
def my_timer(orig_func):
    """returns time orig_func took to run"""
    import time

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time() - t1
        print('{} ran in: {} sec'.format(orig_func.__name__, t2)) # this is interpreted second
        return result # this is interpreted first
    return wrapper

@my_timer
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name, age))


display_info("Aldona", 22)
```

I would expect this wrapper to run print statement first, then return `result` variable which contains the value of the function. Why is this not the case?

Comment: It's not printing `result` at all. No part of this code says to print that. If it did, you would see a `None` in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding where the printout is occurring. Your `display_info` function prints its results, and doesn't return anything useful (it returns `None` by default). So in `wrapper`, it's the `orig_func(...)` call that causes the printout to occur before your timing related `print` call.

If you want the order of the output to match your expectations, you don't need to change the decorator code, instead you need to change `display_info` to `return` the string it builds, and change the calling code to do `print(display_info(...))`. But then you might want to rename the `display_info` function since it doesn't do any displaying by itself....

Comment: Let me try to be more precise. 'orig_func(...)' is called in a wrapper and it's value assigned to variable 'result', then print statement with the timing, and then 'result' variable is returned. However python interpreter displays 'display_info ran with arguments (Aldona, 22)' before 'display_info ran in 0.0003 sec'

Comment: You're confusing what the printed output of the function is with its return value. The printing in `display_info` happens first (when the wrapper calls the function). Then the wrapper's print happens. Then it returns the value returned by the wrapped function, which is `None` (and that returned value gets ignored, not printed, by the calling code).